# GCloud Deploy Function - code 3 but I dont have problem at the entry point

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I've been trying to deploy my GCloud Function for hours, and I get this error on deploy:

OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.

// My code runs perfectly on my machine and in the functions framework.

and this in the function log:

```
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)       function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/services/api.js:2:15)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)       function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/index.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /workspace/server.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /workspace/app.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /workspace/routes.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /workspace/controllers/function-controller.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  - /workspace/services/api.js
   function-name                2021-04-05 20:09:16.206  Require stack:
```

Comment: The errors are unclear but suggest there's at least one missing file. It may be that the Cloud Functions runtime does not permit one of your modules. It would help if you include `package.json` and either your code or a repro that produces the error.

Comment: Solved! My dotenv dependence was like devDependencies. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! My dotenv dependence was like devDependencies.